# Android: Passing data between activities - multiple intent.putExtra not working?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

Having a very annoying problem with passing data between activities.

This is the code I use to successfully pass the value of a progress bar to a different activity:

```
public void WhenClicked(View view)
{       
    view.clearAnimation();
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.Test.QUESTION");        

    if (progressBar != null) 
    {
        if (progressBar.getProgress() != 0) 
        {
            intent.putExtra("ProgressBarValue", progressBar.getProgress());
        }
    }

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Okay, so that worked. Now, when I change it to this, it blows up:

```
public void WhenClicked(View view, String category)
{       
    view.clearAnimation();
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.Test.QUESTION");        
    intent.putExtra("Category", category);

    if (progressBar != null) 
    {
        if (progressBar.getProgress() != 0) 
        {
            intent.putExtra("ProgressBarValue", progressBar.getProgress());
        }
    }

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I don't understand what the problem is. I've even tried sticking it all into a bundle and adding the bundle as an extra - that just made it crash as well. Maybe I'm being stupid and I've just been staring at my code too long, but any help would be great!

This is my first time with Android and it's killing me!

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Can you add the stack trace from the exception you are getting?

Comment: In what way does it 'blow up'? Do you have some logcat output?

Comment: I'm really new to Eclipse and Android - I really don't know how to do these things.. I'm sorry :( If it's easy, you could maybe tell me how and I'll grab it? And by blows up I mean, when I run it through the emulator, as soon as I press the Start button, it's throws a exception and force closes..

Comment: And by Start button I mean a Start button I have on the Activity, not the actual run button.

Comment: The code inside your whenClicked() looks perfect, as you said it crash after you add the category in, I'd say it is probably caused by other part of your code, since you changed the method signature, post the code calling this method would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you need to create `bundle object(Bundle bnd=new Bundle();)` and next `bnd.putString("param1", "test");`
next create intent:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(current classname.this,nextactivity.class);                    
myIntent.putExtras(bnd);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

In 2nd activity u need to get bundel value like :

```
 Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
 String _getData=bundle.getString("param1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have an activity called QUESTION, you might try to put .class on the end as well as "this" for first param:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, QUESTION.class);
```

if you don't have a QUESTION activity then that is another problem.  I'm assuming your activities are in the same app?

Comment: Yep, I have a "Start" activity - where this code is from - and a "Question" activity. You press the Start button on the "Start" activity and it opens the "Question" activity.

Comment: Does my suggestion fix the problem?  Case is important -- if you spelled the name of your activity "Question" then change the above to "Question.class".

Comment: Unfortunately not.. Still throws an exception.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to send that so bluntly! I'm just stuck as this is all really new to me, so I don't fully understand what this is even doing.

Comment: Would be good to know if the exception is happening in this class or in the Question class.  Have you figured out how to get into the Debug view and set breakpoints?

Comment: Yes, I haven't tried that though as I narrowed it down (by just commenting out) that it is exception is thrown on the "intent.putExtra("Category", category);" line.

Comment: You might try changing the name from "Category" -- that may have special meaning.

Comment: Better you put both of your class. then someone may be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

I believe, the activity which should handle this intent action `com.android.Test.QUESTION` does not understand your category i.e `intent.putExtra("Category", category);`.

You can try fixing it in 2 ways:

1. If the receiving activity is from your own application, then try using explicit intent i.e `Intent intent = new Intent("youCurrentClass","theClassYouWantToCall");` without feeding additional category, this will launch the specified activity. In case of explicit Intent Android system does not do a comparison with the intent-filters to match Intent Object.
2. Change the category section in relation to intent receiving Activity.

Hope this helps,
sku